# Razor pay is not redirecting to checkout page, why?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, razorpay

I am using,

*Xcode - 10.2

*Swift language version - swift 5

*RazorPay framework version - 1.1.1 (pod 'razorpay-pod', '1.1.1')

My problem is when I am calling this,

`razorpay.open(options, displayController: self)`

It gives me an unexpected error (code - 1) with

> /Users/travis/build/razorpay/razorpay-ios/RazorpayIOS/CheckoutOtpelf/Classes/RazorpayCheckoutVC.swift deinitialized

Solutions I tried were,

1. Github community says to hide navigation bar before calling open function(https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-pod/issues/42).
2. Used multiple framework version of razor pay
3. Tried with swift 4.2 also
4. I have cleaned my project, deleted derived data and rebuilt it.

Here's my code

```
import Razorpay

class controller: RazorpayPaymentCompletionProtocol{
        private var razorpay: Razorpay!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        razorpay = Razorpay.initWithKey("test_key", andDelegate: self)
}

func openRazorPay(){
        let options = [
            "amount" : "12.00"
        ]
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        razorpay.open(options, displayController: self)
}

func onPaymentSuccess(_ payment_id: String) {
        print("success")
}

func onPaymentError(_ code: Int32, description str: String) {
        print("Failure")
}

}
```

This framework supports Android, but not for iOS. I want to get the payment flow. If anyone has any solution, share with me.

Answer (score 1):

As I face the same issue......

What I did differently is I take a static amount value 100 and pass the other data as it is.....and I make payment process...it works...open the payment window.

If your amount value less than 100 then it happens...as per doc, the amount we are assigning in the param consider it as a paisa....Try with this one and you will get expected result..

Here what the amount you are passing, make a multiply with 100 e.g 1 x 100. The internal processing will be count it as INR 1, but their calculation is consider it as paisa. So you passed value 100 means 100 paisa and in payment window it will show INR 1.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue And All of the parameters which i was sending to the options was right.

But the issue was when we try to open RazorPay screen for payment was getting the issue of the RazorpayCheckoutVC.swift deinitialized

In my case my parent viewController was presented so i just changed the navigation code of present to the push and then it worked.

So as per my understanding it should be as

NavigationController -> Push ViewController -> RazorPaycheckoutVC.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks Bro.

Comment: @Adwait can you share your code here?

Comment: @Jaydip As per my understanding you need to update your previous controller to push and not present. 
Because we can't present a controller on a presented controller unless we use another navigation controller.

Comment: @AdwaitGaikwad I already push it.

Comment: Hey @Jaydip Sorry for late response 
But can you check that the other parameter's you're sending to the payment process are right?

Comment: Also please check the @Gourav Joshi 's Ans. it puts more clarity on what might be wrong with you